# WPF Performance problem in Localization with large Canvas which is full of DynamicResource

Tags: c#, wpf

We are working on single UserControl subway map which supports localization for 4 languages(English, Chinese, Japanese, Korean) for our legacy application which already provides subway map with single png file. We chosed ResourceDictionary based globalization which mentioned here(https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/515960/Globalization-in-WPF-using-ResourceDictionary). We drew the subway line with Path and made every 616 station names with seperated TextBlocks like

`<TextBlock Foreground="#ff000000" FontSize="5.50" Canvas.Left="xxx" Canvas.Top="yyy"  Text="{DynamicResource keyStationName1" />`
`<TextBlock Foreground="#ff000000" FontSize="5.50" Canvas.Left="xxx" Canvas.Top="yyy" Text="{DynamicResource keyStationName2" />`
`...`
`<TextBlock Foreground="#ff000000" FontSize="5.50" Canvas.Left="xxx" Canvas.Top="yyy" Text="{DynamicResource keyStationName616" />`

This worked well, but we found there is seconds of delay when we change the language. This delay increases to at least 3 seconds when we change language from English to Chinese or Japanese first time after application started.
I confirmed that there was almost zero delay with ResourceDictionary change process when user clicked the language change button, so it seems that most delay happens during rendering process because it have to change text of every Textblocks every time. Is there any way to reduce or avoid this delay?

Comment: why not use bindings? why use dynamic resources in the first place?

Comment: Our legacy application already uses resource dictionary and dynamic resources to localization, and in fact our team were intended to make a single subway map UserControl Library that also can be reused in our next project. so our manager wanted that designers can maintain the control with MS Blend and inhouse XAML tool only, without any developer's help.

Comment: ooof...but if you create a custom control it would be 100% reusable as well but you would have all the benefits of MVVM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could using a [list box](https://wpf-tutorial.com/list-controls/listbox-control/) to list all of the stations (Translations may now have to be done in the code behind/viewmodel instead improve this)?

If the stations need to be in unique locations on the map instead of in a list (Unclear in question)it may be worth creating a collection of the strings in the view model, changing all strings behind and then use [OnPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/how-to-implement-the-inotifypropertychanged-interface) to notify the UI of the update. This will be a single update instead of re-rendering for every single string on the UI.

C#:

```
//I suggest a tuple/dict for this so you can relate the keys and their 
//respective strings for re-translation
Collection<type> StationNames = ......

UpdateAllStationNames()
{
 //Update all the names using your translation implementation
 OnPropertyChanged("StationNames");
}
```

XAML:

```
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding StationNames[0]"} />
    //etc etc...
```

I believe this must be a rendering issue as you theorised as I have used a very similar solution to do translations in a large program for my business in the past and noticed no performance issues when switching, and there must have been well over 600 strings in that (Spread across the program on different views).

Hope this helps!

Comment: this is a comment not an answer

Comment: I tried it and there was much more performance improvements. No-delay was unable maybe because our application shows 600+ TextBlocks in one control of one view... Anyway, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try to load data pragmatically from app.xaml.cs using BackgroundWorker

```
public void SetLanguageDictionary(string lang)
{
  ResourceDictionary dict = new ResourceDictionary();
  //switch (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ToString())
  switch (lang)
   {
       case "english":
         dict.Source = new Uri("Lang\\win_en_US.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
         break;
       case "hindi":
         dict.Source = new Uri("Lang\\win_hi_IN.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
         break;
        }
     //this.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(dict);
     Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(dict);
 }
```

Comment: Our application preloads dictionary when application starts so it seems there was no performance improvement.... Thank you for your help anyway!

Comment: Preloading is unpredictable, it can slow UI rendering, thats why if you use Background worker for loading language it will reduce loading effect, showing loading window will not fix problem but will make delay cool